# Surjective equivariant maps from spheres to complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a finite CW complex with a fixed point free involution, and suppose that every equivariant map $f:S^d \to X$ is surjective, for some fixed integer $d$. Can we deduce anything about the homotopy type of $X$?

If $d=1$, then $X$ must be homeomorphic to $S^1$, but (unsurprisingly) the case $d>1$ seems much harder.

Comment: Here is a family of counter-examples that may be useful. Consider the $ S^{2n+1} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$ with co-ords $(x_{1},y_{1},...,x_{n+1},x_{n+1})$. Consider the involution given by rotating each $(x_{i},y_{i})$ plane by $\pi$. Then for $k < n$, the inclusion of $S^{2k + 1} = \{ x_{k+1} = y_{k+1} = .... = x_{n+1} = y_{n+1} = 0\}$ is equivariant but not surjective.

Comment: It seems to me that the two ways this can fail are sharply different. (1) There will be plenty of examples where there is no equivariant map (though not in the $d=1$ case if $X$ is connected).

Comment: (2) If there is a such a map then you can ask whether every map homotopic to it is surjective. So a part of the question becomes, if $q:\mathbb RP^d\to Y$ is surjective and if every map homotopic to $q$is surjective then what does this imply about $Y$ (and $q$).

Comment: Exactly, it's your second case that interests me. Can $Y$ have the homotopy type of any finite CW complex, or does the fact that all maps homotopic to $q$ are surjective somehow restrict the homotopy type?